# Xamarin Sqlite-Net Insert (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I have a very strange problem that I can't figure out. I cannot insert a new item into my Sqlite DB. I keep receiving this error:-

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I literally have no idea why and have the exact same code working and saving other tables within the application.

Here is my code:-

**User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        this.Name = " ";
        this.EmailAddress = " ";
    }
}
```

**UserManager.cs**

```
public class UserManager 
{
    UserRepository repository; 

    public UserManager(SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        repository = new UserRepository (conn);
    }

    public User GetDriver(int id)
    {
        return repository.GetDriver(id);
    }

    public IList<User> GetDrivers()
    {
        return new List<User>(repository.GetDrivers());
    }

    public int SaveDriver(User item)
    {
        return repository.SaveDriver(item);
    }

    public int DeleteDriver(int id)
    {
        return repository.DeleteDriver(id);
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.cs**

```
public class UserRepository
{
    UserDatabase db = null;

    public UserRepository(SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        db = new UserDatabase(conn);
    }

    public User GetDriver(int id)
    {
        return db.GetDriverItem(id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetDrivers()
    {
        return db.GetAllDriverItems();
    }

    public int SaveDriver(User item)
    {
        return db.SaveDriverItem(item);
    }

    public int DeleteDriver(int id)
    {
        return db.DeleteDriverItem(id);
    }
}
```

**UserDatabase.cs**

```
public class UserDatabase
{
    static object locker = new object();
    public SQLiteConnection database;
    public string path;

    public UserDatabase(SQLiteConnection conn)
    {
        database = conn;
        database.CreateTable<User>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllDriverItems () {
        lock (locker) {
            return (from i in database.Table<User>() select i).ToList();
        }
    }

    public User GetDriverItem (int id) 
    {
        lock (locker) {
            return database.Table<User>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
        }
    }

    public int SaveDriverItem (User item) 
    {
        lock (locker) {
            if (item.ID != 0) {
                database.Update(item);
                return item.ID;
            } else {
                return database.Insert(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public int DeleteDriverItem(int id) 
    {
        lock (locker) {
            return database.Delete<User>(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Application.cs (In Android)**

```
public class UserApp : Application
{
    public static UserApp Current { get; private set; }

    public UserManager UserManager { get; set; }

    SQLiteConnection conn;

    public UserApp(IntPtr handle, global::Android.Runtime.JniHandleOwnership transfer)
        : base(handle, transfer)
    {
        Current = this;
    }

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate();

        var sqliteFilename = "UserItemDB.db3";
        string libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
        conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.Generic.SQLitePlatformGeneric(), path);

        UserManager = new UserManager(conn);

        User testUser= new User();
        testUser.Name = "Dave";
        testUser.EmailAddress = "Dave@Gmail.com";
        UserApp.Current.UserManager.SaveDriver(testUser);
    }
```

Here is my stack trace:-

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at     System.Reflection.MonoProperty.GetValue (System.Object obj, System.Object[]     index) [0x00031] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at     SQLite.Net.TableMapping+Column.GetValue (System.Object obj) [0x00000] in     <filename unknown>:0 
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at     SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Insert (System.Object obj, System.String extra,     System.Type objType) [0x00098] in <filename unknown>:0 
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at     SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Insert (System.Object obj) [0x00012] in <filename     unknown>:0 
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at     Project.DataLayer.UserDatabase.SaveDriverItem (Project.BusinessLayer.Models.User     item) [0x00038] in     C:\Users\phill\Desktop\Work\ProjectTEST\Project\Project.Shared\DataLayer\UserDat    abase.cs:42 
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at     Project.DataAccessLayer.UserRepository.SaveDriver     (Project.BusinessLayer.Models.User item) [0x00001] in     C:\Users\phill\Desktop\Work\ProjectTEST\Project\Project.Shared\DataAccessLayer\U    serRepository.cs:30 
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at     Project.BusinessLayer.Managers.UserManager.SaveDriver     (Project.BusinessLayer.Models.User item) [0x00001] in     C:\Users\phill\Desktop\Work\ProjectTEST\Project\Project.Shared\BusinessLayer\Man    agers\UserManager.cs:33 
08-09 17:07:32.423 E/mono    (31670):   at Project.Droid.UserApp+    <getDriverDetails>d__16.MoveNext () [0x000e2] in     C:\Users\phill\Desktop\Work\ProjectTEST\Project\Project.Droid\Application.cs:75
```

Comment: I'm getting the same thing and it's driving me crazy. I've reverted to just using SQL commands for now but that is not ideal.

Comment: Hey @BrettG86 I think I solved my issue, is yours similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - After a long headache I finally figured out the issue.

Okay so the NullObject refers to the database file itself. The structure of the DB could not be changed and my application couldn't create a new DB due to some settings in Xamarin. Not 100% sure which of these was the exact answer but my project finally worked shortly after...

**In VS go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android > Tick "Preserve Application Data"**

I think this is the main issue ^^. I also had checked/unchecked others too.

**Project > Project.Properties > Android Options > Tick Shared Runtime & Fast Deployment And next tab Linker = None.**

Not sure which of the above solved my issue but it's running perfectly

Comment: Unfortunately didn't solve my issue. You did say it only occurred on inserts to this one table but it occurs for every table for me.

Comment: Okay this worked for me if I predefined the database schema in an external editor and forced the autoincrement of primary keys myself by defining the id's as INTEGER rather than INT. Thanks.

Comment: As a test, run that Tasky example in your IDE. The code for that is working well, run through your VS setup trying different options to check and see which one starts working?

Comment: @BrettG86, what do you mean by defining id as INTEGER rather than INT